# JAVA - call a part of the main method from another class

Tags: java

At the moment I got two classes. public class Start and public class Frame_Main.

I am controlling public class Frame_Main through a GUI, where I type something in and press the button afterwards which activates the ActionListener.
Afterwards the input becomes a output in the console.

After the input through the GUI I want to call the Start class and check if the input is the same as some user answers that I prepared, but I cant find a way to call the function to achive that, Eclipse always shows me error when I try to create a public void or class with the function in it.

Start:

```
public class Start {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 //deleted some variables to make the code look cleaner
 auswahl = frame_main.auswahl;
 //I want to call this while loop 
    while(run){
        System.out.println("Welche Zahl ist vorhanden? \nDual, Hexa, Oktal oder Dezimal?");

        if((auswahl).equals("Dual") || (auswahl).equals("dual"))
        {
            System.out.println("Dual wurde ausgewählt");
            System.out.println("Dezimal: " + dezimalzahlen.dualUmrechnung());
            System.out.println("Oktal: " + oktaldezimalzahlen.dualUmrechnung());
            System.out.println("Hexa: " + hexadezimalzahlen.dualUmrechnung());
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
        }
        else 
        {
            if((auswahl).equals("Hexa") || (auswahl).equals("hexa"))
            {
                System.out.println("Hexa wurde ausgewählt");
                System.out.println("Dezimal: " + dezimalzahlen.hexadezimalUmrechnung());
                System.out.println("Dual: " + dualzahlen.hexadezimalUmrechnung());
                System.out.println("Oktal: " + oktaldezimalzahlen.hexadezimalUmrechnung());
                System.out.println("-------------------------");
            }
            else
            {
                if((auswahl).equals("Oktal") || (auswahl).equals("oktal"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Oktal wurde ausgewählt");
                    System.out.println("Dual: " + dualzahlen.oktaldezimalUmrechnung());
                    System.out.println("Dezimal: " + dezimalzahlen.oktaldezimalUmrechnung());
                    System.out.println("Hexa: " + hexadezimalzahlen.oktaldezimalUmrechnung());
                    System.out.println("-------------------------");
                }
                else
                {
                    if((auswahl).equals("Dezimal") || (auswahl).equals("dezimal") )
                    {
                        System.out.println("Dezimal wurde ausgewählt");
                        System.out.println("Dual: " + dualzahlen.dezimalUmrechnung());
                        System.out.println("Oktal: " + oktaldezimalzahlen.dezimalUmrechnung());
                        System.out.println("Hexa: " + hexadezimalzahlen.dezimalUmrechnung());
                        System.out.println("-------------------------");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if((auswahl).equals("Exit") || (auswahl).equals("exit"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Das Programm wurde beendet.");
                            run = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Keine Übereinstimmung, bitte erneut versuchen");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

}

Frame_Main:

```
public String auswahl = "";
public void createTextField()
{

    jbutton1_go.addActionListener (new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (jtextfield1_bezeichnung.getText().length() <= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Error 404: Kein Zahlensystem wurde angegeben");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println ("Vorhandenes Zahlensystem: " + jtextfield1_bezeichnung.getText());
                auswahl = jtextfield1_bezeichnung.getText();
                //after getting the input value I would like to call the while loop
            }

            if(jtextfield1_zahl.getText().length() <= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Error 404: Keine Zahl wurde angegeben");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println ("Vorhandene Zahl: " + jtextfield1_zahl.getText());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: move the code in main function to new function and do with it ,

Comment: Could you put the line `auswahl = frame_main.auswahl;` **inside** the while loop instead of before it? That way you don't need to call the loop at all, it will keep checking by itself. If I've understood your code properly.

Comment: @NeilMasson when I try to create 'class test(){ ....}' around it:
-Syntax error on token 'class' new expected
-Syntax error insert }, ; to complete statement

Comment: do as the error says... you are missing closing braces  }

Comment: @Ciara sorry I probably should have clarified that I want to get rid of the while loop, I only implented it because I used to get the input by using the scanner and the console

Comment: Are you getting a out of memory exception?

Comment: so what is it that you want to do?

Comment: @IrinaAvram I want that the ActionListener from the button (jbutton1_go) takes the input from my GUI, puts it into the variable 'auswahl' and afterwards calls my If statement in public class Start, to compare 'auswahl' with the prepared answers.
I already have access to the variable 'auswahl' in my public class Start, I just need a method to get rid of the while loop and call the if statements instead by putting it into a class or something

Comment: and what is wrong with the check() method from my answer? Minus the while and the displaying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a method for your checks, it makes no sense having them all in main. If you create a static method you can call it by:

```
Start.check(auswahl);
```

If not, you should instantiate Start. Here your start class:

```
public class Start {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
 //deleted some variables to make the code look cleaner
 auswahl = frame_main.auswahl;

}   


public static check(String auswahl) {
    //I want to call this while loop 
    while(run){
        System.out.println("Welche Zahl ist vorhanden? \nDual, Hexa, Oktal oder Dezimal?");

        if((auswahl).equals("Dual") || (auswahl).equals("dual"))
        {
            System.out.println("Dual wurde ausgewählt");
            System.out.println("Dezimal: " + dezimalzahlen.dualUmrechnung());
            System.out.println("Oktal: " + oktaldezimalzahlen.dualUmrechnung());
            System.out.println("Hexa: " + hexadezimalzahlen.dualUmrechnung());
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
        }
        else 
        {
            if((auswahl).equals("Hexa") || (auswahl).equals("hexa"))
            {
                System.out.println("Hexa wurde ausgewählt");
                System.out.println("Dezimal: " + dezimalzahlen.hexadezimalUmrechnung());
                System.out.println("Dual: " + dualzahlen.hexadezimalUmrechnung());
                System.out.println("Oktal: " + oktaldezimalzahlen.hexadezimalUmrechnung());
                System.out.println("-------------------------");
            }
            else
            {
                if((auswahl).equals("Oktal") || (auswahl).equals("oktal"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Oktal wurde ausgewählt");
                    System.out.println("Dual: " + dualzahlen.oktaldezimalUmrechnung());
                    System.out.println("Dezimal: " + dezimalzahlen.oktaldezimalUmrechnung());
                    System.out.println("Hexa: " + hexadezimalzahlen.oktaldezimalUmrechnung());
                    System.out.println("-------------------------");
                }
                else
                {
                    if((auswahl).equals("Dezimal") || (auswahl).equals("dezimal") )
                    {
                        System.out.println("Dezimal wurde ausgewählt");
                        System.out.println("Dual: " + dualzahlen.dezimalUmrechnung());
                        System.out.println("Oktal: " + oktaldezimalzahlen.dezimalUmrechnung());
                        System.out.println("Hexa: " + hexadezimalzahlen.dezimalUmrechnung());
                        System.out.println("-------------------------");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if((auswahl).equals("Exit") || (auswahl).equals("exit"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Das Programm wurde beendet.");
                            run = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Keine Übereinstimmung, bitte erneut versuchen");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: you beat me @Irina! ;) nice one

Comment: System.out from a Swing JFrame does not make the most sense to me...?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go here would be called **Refactoring**

You have one console appliaction with a `main()` that prints your output to `System.out`.

Now you want to go GUI and *cannot reuse* your code, because `System.out` has no place in GUI applications.

*Now, what do the two have in common?*

They share a method where you put in some data and then print out some results.

Consider this method:

```
 public String showUmrechnungen(String auswahl, String zahl) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter();

    //Your code from main(). Replace System.out.println with out.println()

    out.flush();
    return sw.toString();
 }
```

You could use that in *both* of your situations:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Start instance = new Start();  
   while(running) {
      //Get the input
      String zahl = readZahl();
      String auswahl = readAuswahl();

      System.out.println(instance.showUmrechnungen(auswahl, zahl));        
   }
 }
```

And in your Swing-App:

```
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
       Start instance = new Start();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame_Main.this, 
           instance.showUmrechnungen(jtextfield1_bezeichnung.getText(),
                jtextfield1_zahl.getText()));                              
    }
```

Of cause, this is only the **general idea** of how to attack this situation. In your case, you'd have to think about input like "Exit" and what to do with that. So maybe it would be better to *pass in* a `PrintStream` and return a boolean for continue or not:

```
 public boolean showUmrechnungen(String auswahl, String zahl, PrintStream out) {
 }
```